# Why isn't all the data fron Standard Output and Error not received in wpf application however it is in a console application?

Tags: c#, wpf, console, redirectstandardoutput, standard-error

When you call the RedirectCommandStream in the code below it works perfectly in a console application, however in a wpf application it misses out the standard output data and some of the standard error output. The string builder that is outputed from the method is then used to display on the wpf application.

Can someone please help, been stuck on this for a long time?

```
        class ProcessStreamRedirection
{
    private static StringBuilder OutputBuilder = null;

    public static StringBuilder RedirectCommandStreams(string FileName,string Arguments)
    {
        Process Process;
        Process = new Process();
        Process.StartInfo.FileName = FileName;
        Process.StartInfo.Arguments = Arguments;
        Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        Process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        Process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(DataHandler);
        OutputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        Process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(DataHandler);

        OutputBuilder.AppendLine(string.Format("Starting process: {0} {1}", Process.StartInfo.FileName ,Process.StartInfo.Arguments));

        Process.Start();

        Process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        Process.BeginErrorReadLine();

        Process.WaitForExit();

        if (OutputBuilder.Length > 0)
        {
            OutputBuilder.AppendLine(string.Format("Output:\n{0}\n", OutputBuilder));
        }

        Process.Close();

        return OutputBuilder;
    }

    private static void DataHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
        {
            OutputBuilder.AppendLine(outLine.Data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it correct in memory and just the display is wrong? From what you said it sounds like the display code is the only place there could be a bug.

Comment: No i've checked the memory by debugging it and it's not correct there either. I don't think it is to do with the display code. Can't seem to figure this one out

Comment: Odd, everything looks right and I have done something very, very close to this in WPF before. The only difference is that I did the synchronous version of reading the output. Have you tried that?